# For Each Value to array vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to extract a value from a process array to myArray:

**File:** MyClass.vb

```
Public Function getTheRunningProcess()
Dim MyArray As Array
 For Each prso In Process.GetProcesses(System.Environment.MachineName)
    'This is the value i want to extract and put it in a Array
    MyArray() = prso.ProcessName.ToString
 Next
 'Now i need to return the MyArray so i can access its value from anywhere
  Return MyArray
End Function
```

So i can access this value from anywhere like so:

**File:** Form1.vb

```
For Each MyValue As TheValueFromFunction_getTheRunningProcess()
  Listbox.item.addItem(MyValue)
Next
```

Now you might be thinking i can directly use the process in the **File:** Form1.vb but here is the situation, i have to use this function over and over again in different form as the application demands it has to be.

So if this is possible then how?

Or if there is any other way to do this?

Please show me the right path.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function getTheRunningProcess() As Generic.List(Of String)
    Dim processList As New Generic.List(Of String)
    For Each prso In Process.GetProcesses(System.Environment.MachineName)
        processList.Add(prso.ProcessName.ToString)
    Next
    Return processList
End Function
```

You could try doing it with Lists... And then

```
Dim myProccessList = getTheRunningProcess()
For Each p In myProccessList
    'Do something with p
Next
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i have got a null value in my listbox ;(

Comment: Did you forget the New keyword? If not,
how are you adding the items to your listbox?
For Each p In myProccessList
   listBox.Items.Add(p)
Next

Works for me